# Unity how to affect variable from other classes with raycast. By using scripting and visual scripting bolt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state-machine, raycasting

I need to blind an enemy ai with the use of raycast.
When the raycast collides with the enemy, the boolean of the enemy isblinded must be set to true.
I have refrenced the enemy gameobject, but the console log gives me this error.
NullRefrenceException: Object refrence not set to an instance of an object Raycast.Update() (at Assets/Scripts/Raycast.cs.23).
The assignment is to detect if the raycast hits the enemy and transfer the state with visual scipting.
This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Raycast : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] LayerMask enemyLayer;
    RaycastHit hitinfo;
    public GameObject enemy;

    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Update()
    {

        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward));
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 20, Color.red);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitinfo, 100, enemyLayer))
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit");
            Debug.Log(hitinfo.collider.gameObject.name);
            //enemy is blinded is true
            enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().isBlinded = true;
            Debug.Log(enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().isBlinded);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 20, Color.green);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

I tried using the Enemy enemyscript class, but that doesn't let me add the enemy object in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a reference to the GameObject itself rather than the script/component on the GameObject.

Try:

```
 private EnemyScript enemyScript;
```

...

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitinfo, 100, enemyLayer))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");
        Debug.Log(hitinfo.collider.gameObject.name);
        //enemy is blinded is true
        
        enemyScript = hitinfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyScript>();
        enemyScript = true;
        Debug.Log(enemyScript.isBlinded);
    }
```